# C struct initialization with macro value

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, undefined-symbol

I know C++ and I am learning C. I would like to define nullptr as NULL, but when I initialize a struct using brackets it causes an error and says expected '}'. I'm using the visual studio compiler and a sample of my code is bellow:

```
#define nullptr NULL;

typedef struct
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} 
Node;

//works fine
Node myNode1;
myNode1.data = 1;
myNode1.next = nullptr;

//works fine
Node myNode2 = {1, NULL};

//error E0067   expected a '}'
Node myNode3 = {1, nullptr };
```

Comment: You've put a semicolon at the end of the macro. So after the precompilation, the last line would actually become `Node myNode3 {1, NULL;};`

Comment: *I would like to define nullptr as NULL* – achieves ... what?

Comment: I'd not define nullptr in C but just use NULL. Redefining common (standard) things makes the code less readable/maintainable. Imitating another language usually makes things worse. Since there is barely any reason to prefer C over C++ (even on embedded systems), just use C++ instead of emulating C++ in C.

Comment: @Erlkoenig besides mentioning the semicolon what you wrote should be *the* answer.

Comment: Just as a side note - never ever define macro names with small letters. It's common convention to use capital letters for macro names, otherwise it makes the code harder to read and hard to distinguish what is a macro and what is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `nullptr` as

```
#define nullptr NULL
```

with no trailing `;`.